# How do browsers handle SSL certificate?

Tags: algorithm, ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, sha1

I'm wondering how do browsers handle `SSL certificate` that transmitted from web server?

I understand `RSA algorithm` is important here, but why we use `SHA-1` here too? and what the role of `SHA-1 algorithm`?

Can anybody explain the process to me in detail?

Comment: There a few very good articles about SSL. Did you read them? For example: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/59566/ssl-certificate-chain-verification or  http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20803/how-does-ssl-tls-work

Comment: Here is another article that directly answers your question and briefly explain how SSL uses SHA-1 https://konklone.com/post/why-google-is-hurrying-the-web-to-kill-sha-1

Comment: @MichałKomorowski  Thanks for the good articles, and I got another quesion after reading [why-google-is-hurrying-the-web-to-kill-sha-1](https://konklone.com/post/why-google-is-hurrying-the-web-to-kill-sha-1): as the article says, browser use **SHA-1** to calculate certificate, if the result matches the **signed SHA-1** that the certificate offered as proof, then browser can be assured that the certificate on offer is the same one the Certificate Authority signed. But what if a man-in-the-middle attack replace the whole data including certificate and the **signed SHA-1** offered itself?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to programming. security.stackexchange.com is a better forum for this kind of question and there already several similar questions there with very good answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first question was how a browser uses SHA-1 in the context of SSL. The full answer can be found [here](https://konklone.com/post/why-google-is-hurrying-the-web-to-kill-sha-1). The short answer is that SHA-1 is used to confirm that a certificate offered as a proof is the same one that was signed by CA.

As to the second question (*But what if a man-in-the-middle attack replace the whole data including certificate and the signed SHA-1 offered itself?*). A word 'Signed' is a key here. A man-in-the-middle can replace a certificate. However, this certificate will not be trusted by a browser because it won't be signed by Certificate Authority. An attacker cannot generate a certificate signed by CA because he/she doesn't know a private key of CA.